# Error checking whether an element is in a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, file-io, io

i am trying to check whether certain elements are in a list, and to execute numerical update but i keep getting an error (below).

---

```
"if h2output[1] not in h1output == True or h2output[2] not in h1output == True:
IndexError: list index out of range"
```

---

```
doublewin = 0

h1output = []
h2output = []
h3output = []
v1output = []
v2output = []
v3output = []
d1output = []
d2output = []


for i in h1:
    if i not in h1output:
        h1output.append(i)
    if len(h1output) == 2:
        doublewin += 1


for i in h2:
    if i not in h2output:
        h2output.append(i)

if len(h2output) == 2:
    if h2output[1] not in h1output == True or h2output[2] not in h1output == True:
        doublewin += 1
```

Comment: use `len()` to check the length of the list before indexing it

Comment: What are `h1` and `h2`? You also do not need the `== True` statements, you are already checking that with `h2output[1] not in h1output`, which will either evaluate to `True` or `False`

Comment: it seems **h1output** is one **list**, not **set** or **dict**, or uses `list.index()`, but `list.index()` will loop the list.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Remove True booleans in if condition. You have hardcoded indexes in h2output[1] and  h2output[2]. Either one of them is causing the issue. Please check the size of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `len(h2output)==2`, it has only 2 positions, which in python starts at zero, therefore `h2output[2]` is out of bounds, index must be `0` or `1`

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcoded indexes in `h2output[1]` and `h2output[2]`. Either one of them is causing the issue. Please check the size of the list.

Remove True booleans in if condition as it is unnecessary.